# wxFormBuilder : How do I repeat info across multiple tabs?

Tags: windows, wxformbuilder

I am building a test GUI to control/test the product. The product sends status info periodically. There are so many features that I've grouped similar features across several notebooks (tabs). I'd like to display the common status info on all tabs in the same X/Y position. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Got a hint from a co-worker to add the dashboard to the top level panel so that it resides in the same file as the code that adds the panels (aka tabs). This would not work while the dashboard resided under a staticboxsizer, kept getting complaints about "wxstaticbox can't be used as a window parent". Changed the staticboxsizer to boxsizer and the code runs successfully.